# Can someone explain varnish vmod use following private pointer in different cases PRIV_CALL, PRIV_TASK,PRIV_TOP,PRIV_VCL?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am looking to maintain a local state for host name that varnish receive in the vmod. which of the PRIV_CALL, PRIV_TASK,PRIV_TOP,PRIV_VCL pointers to use and which scenario?this is for the understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be of help to read the docs for the vmod: https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/doc/sphinx/reference/vmod.rst
From the docs:

- PRIV_CALL "per call" private pointers are useful to cache/store state relative to the specific call or its arguments, for instance a compiled regular expression specific to a regsub() statement or simply caching the most recent output of some expensive operation. These private pointers live for the duration of the loaded VCL.
- PRIV_TASK "per task" private pointers are useful for state that applies to calls for either a specific request or a backend request. For instance this can be the result of a parsed cookie specific to a client. Note that PRIV_TASK contexts are separate for the client side and the backend side, so use in vcl_backend_* will yield a different private pointer from the one used on the client side. These private pointers live only for the duration of their task.
- PRIV_TOP "per top-request" private pointers live for the duration of one request and all its ESI-includes. They are only defined for the client side. When used from backend VCL subs, a NULL pointer will be passed. These private pointers live only for the duration of their top level request
- PRIV_VCL "per vcl" private pointers are useful for such global state that applies to all calls in this VCL, for instance flags that determine if regular expressions are case-sensitive in this vmod or similar. The PRIV_VCL object is the same object that is passed to the VMOD's event function. This private pointer lives for the duration of the loaded VCL.

I'd probably say if you wish to keep track of the Host in the client side, then priv_task is what you are looking for.